# How to pass login credentials to "Activiti Explorer" using the post method?

Tags: authentication, activiti

I'm trying to access Activiti Explorer from my Liferay portlet. My idea would be to bypass the Activiti login by adding username and password to the URL.
Something like:

```
   <a href="http://localhost:8082/activiti-explorer/#processmodel/50?ID_=kermit&PWD_=kermit">Vedi Grafico</a>
```

Disabling the login function would be good too, but I don't think it can be done. Does anyone have any ideas on how to best proceed?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea put the user and the password in a hiperlink. But if you have clear ideas, the best way for do this is ParameterAutologin.

Ensure that you have active this hook in your portal-ext.properties, if that is not the case you should add the ParameterAutoLogin and reboot the portal:

```
auto.login.hooks=com.liferay.portal.security.auth.ParameterAutoLogin
```

then if your portal login is by screenname you put this url:

http://localhost:8082/path&parameterAutoLoginLogin=test&parameterAutoLoginPassword=test

If your portal login is by email you put this url:

http://localhost:8082/path&parameterAutoLoginLogin=test@domain.com&parameterAutoLoginPassword=test

This works with all the urls of your portal. No matters the path.